# Firebase Database reference to event listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi in my Firebase database I am trying to access one child "Chatmessages", gathering all its keys and using them to locate their corresponding keys in the child "Users" and gathering its information. I am doing this this through querying twice using eventlisteners. Although how would I apply this to chatIDref in my loadUserlist() method.

*Structure of database:*
[image: Figure 1]

```
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    chatIdRef = rootRef.child("Chatmessages").child(last);
    eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String uid = ds.getKey();
                usersRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        Boolean onlineStatus = dataSnapshot.child("onlineStatus").getValue(Boolean.class);
                        String status = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", image + " / " + name + " / " + onlineStatus + " / " + status);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                };
                usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    chatIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    chatIdRef.keepSynced(true);
    userlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    userlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    return userView;
}

public void loadUserList() {
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(
            User.class,
            R.layout.userlist_layout,
            UserViewHolder.class,
            chatIdRef
    )
```

Comment: I don't understand whay are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of the loadUserList method?